# Gráficos de distribuciones de densidad usando cdplot

Tags: r, matemáticas

He utilizado la función cdplot para representar una serie de datos:
El código:

```
cdplot(y~x,dat)
```

Un ejemplo de los datos (nótese que es un ejemplo que no corresponde a los gráficos elaborados, los cuales utilizan un corpus mayor):

```
y        x    
3.00     0.0
2.75     0.0
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.2
2.25     0.2
3        0.3
2        0.3
2.25     0.4
1.75     0.4
1.75     0.5
2        0.5
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.7
1        0.7
0.54     0.8
0        0.8
0.54     0.9
0        0.9
0        1.0
0        1.0
```

El gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puede observarse mi variable independiente es discreta (tomo solo ciertos valores), y mi variable dependiente es también discreta (son 11 niveles, de 0 a 1 en pasos de 0.1).

El gráfico corresponde a un gráfico de densidades (leer documentación de cdplot).

Mi primera cuestión es pedir asesoramiento estadístico sobre si mis variables discretas son apropiadas para realizar este tipo de análisis.

La segunda cuestión es preguntar por sugerencias para realizar un gráfico similar pero más elegante. Por ejemplo utilizando colores o heat maps.

**Edición primera:**

Siguiendo las indicaciones de la respuesta he procedido a elaborar dos gráficos.

El primero corresponde a un gráfico de desnidad en el que he convertido la variable discreta independiente (y) en categórica, mediante el agrupamiento de valores, para una más fácil lectura. El código utilizado es el siguiente:

```
#Transforming values to categorical
y <- as.character(y)
y[y>=2]<-"high"
y[y < 2 & y >= 1]<-"medium"
y[y<1]<-"low"
#Sort plot by reorganizing levels in the graph
y <- factor(y, levels = c("low","medium","high"))
#Density plot
cdplot(y~x,f, col=heat.colors(y))
```

El problema que tengo ahora es que los nombres en el eje-y no aparecen perfectamente alineados con cada grupo. Me gustaría saber si puedo ajustarlos o inscribirlos sobre la correspondiente distribución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El segundo gráfico que he realizado ha sido un gráfico de tipo mosaico. El problema aquí es que al existir grupos muy pequeños en los datos reales (no en los del ejemplo), las inscripciones quedan fuera del gráfico. Sería estupendo algún consejo para resolverlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada me parece que el ejemplo que muestras no se corresponde con los datos, viendo el eje `y` hay muchos más niveles que los 11 que mencionas (0 a 1 en pasos de 0.1), me da la impresión que se corresponde más bien con los valores del eje `x`, revisalo por las dudas.

Vamos a la parte más concreta de tu pregunta, como darle una mejor apariencia con colores. Para establecer los colores en un `cdplot`(y en muchos otros gráficos) simplemente puedes usar el parámetro `col`, el tema es que necesitas definir una paleta de colores para los 11 niveles que tiene el valor `y`. Hay varias formas de hacer esto. La más simple es usar algunas de las paletas que ya vienen en **R**. Por ejemplo:

```
cdplot(y~x,dat, col=rainbow(n=nlevels(dat$y)))
cdplot(y~x,dat, col=heat.colors(n=nlevels(dat$y)))
cdplot(y~x,dat, col=terrain.colors(n=nlevels(dat$y)))
cdplot(y~x,dat, col=topo.colors(n=nlevels(dat$y)))
```

En este ejemplo `rainbow()`,`heat.colors()`, `terrain.colors()` y `topo.colors()` son funciones que generan una paleta de `n` colores, usaremos la cantidad de `levels` que tiene el eje `y`. Por ejemplo con `topo.colors()` obtienes algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra posibilidad es que crees tu propia paleta, no es más que generar los códigos `rgb` de cada uno de los niveles.

```
paleta <- c("#c6d4e1", "#2f2016", "#fcfaea", "#456789", "#C3D938", "#772877",
            "#7C821E", "#D8B98B", "#7A4012", "#4f2016", "#A3D938")
cdplot(y~x,dat, col=paleta)
```

Y por último, hay varios paquetes de paletas, el más conocido es [`RColorBrewer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html), te ofrece varias funciones para generar distintas combinaciones de colores, por ejemplo: `cdplot(y~x,dat, col=brewer.pal(nlevels(dat$y),"RdYlBu"))`

En cuanto a los datos y al tipo de gráfico, creo que éste no es el mejor gráfico para estos datos, te doy algunas razones por las que pienso esto, pero igual estamos muy cerca de una opinión personal:

En primer lugar un **Conditional Density Plots**, según la documentación:

> Computes and plots conditional densities describing how the
>   conditional distribution of a categorical variable y changes over a
>   numerical variable x.

Sirve para describir como varía la distribución de una variable discreta `y` con respecto a una variable numérica `x` (continua), en tu caso mencionas que las dos son discretas, en el caso de `y` efectivamente lo debe ser ya que `cdplot` verifica que sea un `Factor` pero `x` debe ser numérica (revísalo, por que en caso que sea un `Factor` esto te dará un gráfico algo distinto al esperado, en vez de usar los valores estaría usando el número del `level`).

**¿Esto quiere decir que no puede usarse con dos variables discretas?** no, pero por la naturaleza de la gráfica (continua) tal vez no sea la forma más adecuada ya que justamente en los datos no existe esta continuidad.

El otro punto importante, es que, este tipo de gráfico tal vez es más adecuado cuando manejas un número menor de variables categóricas, cuando tienes más de 2 se hace más difícil, al menos para mi, poder leerlo. Además los datos, tanto en tu gráfico como en el ejemplo que publicaste claramente tiene un cierto sesgo, los valores altos de `y` aparecen con mayor ocurrencia con los valores bajos de `x`. Un `cdplot` se entiende mucho mejor cuando los valores de `y` son  más regulares, por ejemplo gráficos como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que para este tipo de datos te convendría más otro tipo de gráfico, pero, en primer lugar, ¿Que es básicamente lo que queremos mostrar?

```
dat <- read.table(text="x        y    
3.00     0.0
2.75     0.0
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.1
2.75     0.2
2.25     0.2
3        0.3
2        0.3
2.25     0.4
1.75     0.4
1.75     0.5
2        0.5
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.6
1.75     0.7
1        0.7
0.54     0.8
0        0.8
0.54     0.9
0        0.9
0        1.0
0        1.0", header=TRUE)

dat$y <- as.factor(dat$y)

prop.table(table(dat), 1)
```

Algo como esto:

```
      y
x         0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9    1
  0    0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25 0.50
  0.54 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50 0.00
  1    0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  1.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.20 0.20 0.40 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.00
  2    0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  2.25 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  2.75 0.25 0.50 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  3    0.50 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

De hecho creo que es la forma más clara de representar la información, al ser ambos ejes, variables discretas, esta tabla describe bastante bien como se distribuyen los valores de `y` en función de `x`, podemos sacar rápidamente conclusiones como: *Dado un valor `x=0` tenemos un 25% de chances que `y=0.8` otro 25% que `y=0.9` y un 50% que sea `1`*, esto tan solo viendo la primer fila. El problema con el `cdplot` es que cada área corresponde a un valor de `y`, pero si comparas la conclusión anterior con el gráfico que pegue al principio (son los mismos datos) resulta difícil llegar a la misma conclusión, de hecho si vemos un eje vertical justo sobre `x=0`, pareciera que son 4 las áreas que llegan a él cuando en realidad sabemos que `x=0` solo tenemos tres valores posibles de `y`.

Creo que un buen gráfico para mostrar esta información podría ser algo tipo "mosaico". Por ejemplo esto:

```
library("RColorBrewer")

print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%") {
    nx <- nrow(tbl)
    off <- 0.02
    xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
    posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
    ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
    lbl <- ifelse(ptbl[k,] != 0,
                  paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, "\n","y=",colnames(tbl), sep=""),
                  "")
    text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl, cex=0.8)
}


paleta <- brewer.pal(nlevels(dat$y),"RdYlBu")
tbl <- spineplot(dat$y ~ as.factor(dat$x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "") 

for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)
```

Lo cual generaría algo como esto (te sugiero abrirlo en otra solapa para verlo mejor):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunas consideraciones:

- En el eje `x` están todos los valores posibles de esta variable, cada barra corresponde a uno de estos valores
- El ancho de las barras indica la cantidad de casos en la muestra, por ejemplo la barra de `x=1.75` es más ancha que la de `x=1` porque, si ves los datos, hay 3 casos de `x=1.75` contra uno solo de `x=1`
- Para hacer más clara la lectura agregamos el porcentaje y el valor de `y` que corresponde a cada barra `x`. Eventualmente podríamos agregar el porcentaje acumulado si nos interesa.
- Uso una paleta de colores de [`RColorBrewer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) ya que tiene una mejor separación de los colores, además cada color representa un valor de `y` es muy importante que podamos distinguir la separación de estos.
- Estamos usando `spineplot()` que forma parte de la paquetería básica, eventualmente te sugiero investigar este tipo de gráficos en `ggplot2`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho. En efecto las variables estaban invertidas (x por y). Ya lo he editado. Estoy revisando la respuesta, si tengo dudas te pregunto.

Comment: Ok @pyring, ten en cuenta entonces que por ahora  mi respuesta está armada justamente con las columnas invertidas, para el caso es lo mismo. Cuando pueda la editó y ajusto las gráficas.

Comment: Estupendo. Ya he editado mi pregunta a partir de los criterios de tu respuesta. Me quedan algunos detalles que solventar, pero la respuesta es estupenda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: he estado intentando solucionar el problema en el gráfico tipo mosaico pero no lo consigo. ¿Se te ocurre alguna solución medianamente elegante? Si no, quizá sea mejor abrir una nueva pregunta. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @pyring, justo te pensaba decir que abras otra pregunta, por que este último problema es mucho más concreto y vas a tener más posibilidades de respuesta. Publica la pregunta con el código completo, yo por mi parte lo voy a mirar un poco y veo si se me ocurre algo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho. He seguido trabajando con esta última versión del código que compartiste para hacer spinplots. Me preguntaba si es posible asignar el código a un solo valor, digamos,   `plot1`, para poder trabajar con varios gráficos a la vez de manera más dinámica.